# Excel two column of different file comparison and replace next column

Tags: excel, vba, csv, excel-formula

Hi I want to compare two excel files and if any strings in file1 coumun B batches with File2 ColumnA then I want to replace corresponding File2's ColumB with File1 Column C

eg:
if File 1, B3 matches with File2 A5 then I want to replace string in B5 of file 2 with C3 of file1

Answer (score 0):

Assume that ***File1*** location is "C:\test\File1.xlsx"
so you can import ***File1:column A*** values to ***File2:column K*** by formula

```
File2:K1 formule
='C:\test\[File1.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1
File2:K2 formule
='C:\test\[File1.xlsx]Sheet1'!A2
and so on
```

Now it is easy to write formulas in File2 depends on imported values

Answer (score 0):

### Column Comparison Worksheet Update

- Carefully adjust the **const**ants including the **Workbooks**.
- Copy the code into a standard module (e.g. `Module1`).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub updateWorksheet()

    ' Source
    Const srcWb As String = "Source.xlsm"
    Const srcWs As String = "Sheet1"
    Const srcFirstRow As Long = 2
    Const srcCriteria As Variant = "B"
    Const srcValue As Variant = "C"
    ' Target
    Const tgtWb As String = "Target.xlsm"
    Const tgtWs As String = "Sheet2"
    Const tgtFirstRow As Long = 2
    Const tgtCriteria As Variant = "A"
    Const tgtValue As Variant = "B"
    ' Workbooks
    Dim wbSrc As Workbook: Set wbSrc = Workbooks(srcWb)
    'Dim wbSrc As Workbook: Set wbSrc = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wbTgt As Workbook: Set wbTgt = Workbooks(tgtWb)
    'Dim wbTgt As Workbook: Set wbTgt = ThisWorkbook

    ' Write values from Source Range to Source Array.
    Dim src As Worksheet: Set src = wbSrc.Worksheets(srcWs)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = src.Columns(srcCriteria).Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If rng.Row < srcFirstRow Then Exit Sub
    Set rng = src.Range(src.Cells(srcFirstRow, srcCriteria), rng)
    Dim Source(1) As Variant: Source(0) = rng.Value
    Source(1) = rng.Offset(, src.Columns(srcValue).Column - rng.Column).Value

    ' Write values from Target Range to Target Array.
    Dim tgt As Worksheet: Set tgt = wbTgt.Worksheets(tgtWs)
    Set rng = tgt.Columns(tgtCriteria).Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If rng.Row < tgtFirstRow Then Exit Sub
    Set rng = tgt.Range(tgt.Cells(tgtFirstRow, tgtCriteria), rng)
    Dim Target(1) As Variant: Target(0) = rng.Value
    Set rng = rng.Offset(, tgt.Columns(tgtValue).Column - rng.Column)
    Target(1) = rng.Value
    Dim Curr As Variant

    ' Write from Source Array to Target Array.
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(Target(0))
        Curr = Application.Match(Target(0)(i, 1), Source(0), 0)
        If Not IsError(Curr) Then
            Target(1)(i, 1) = Source(1)(Curr, 1)
        End If
    Next i

    ' Write from Target Array to Target Range.
    rng.Value = Target(1)

    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Data transferred.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```